# How to avoid split?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I have this text in the document:"50%"; when I run this function it just returns "50" and after that it returns "%". I dont know why it is spliting the 50 of the %... Can you please tell me how can I avoid this behavior in order to get the complete word "50%", instead "50" and "%"?

```
int astart = 0;
int aend = Doc.Content.End;

//docwords.Words = '50%'
Range docwords = Doc.Range(ref astart, ref aend);

foreach (Range word in docwords.Words)
{
    // here first return "50" and after return "%"
    String wordText = word.Text;
}
```

Comment: Missing context, and very poor explanation. You should give some more and explain the question better. Moreover ignorechars is never used.

Comment: You never use `ignorechars`...

Comment: Its in the definition of a `word`. What does `Doc` define a `word` as? It appears that non-alphanumeric characters are considered their own words. Also, the `ignorechars` does nothing.

Comment: Start Word, type "50%", use Ctrl+Shift+right arrow to select a word.  Yup, two words.

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming you're using Office10 and the Word API.  Based on this @Richard is correct.  Words are broken by punctuation, a space, or being at the start or end of a line.

If you want to avoid the split you may be better off selecting your words using a RegEx and Matches collection.  Something like `Regex.Matches(Document.Text, @"[A-Za-z0-9]+")` may help.  (And stick the punctuation that you want into the square brackets.

Comment: How would he write this code with RegEx expressions instead of iterating through docwords.Words?